# How can I delete a program totally?

Tags: uninstall, krita

I'm using Ubuntu LTS 20.04 and I have installed the program Krita 4.3.0 but yesterday somehow when I go into the full screen mode it freezes and the only thing I can do is end the session and it has a lot of lag.
I already uninstalled the program and I even tried the purge command but the problem still persist.
It only happens on my user because I already tried in other one and it works good, so I guess the configuration corrupted somehow but now I don't know how to fix it.

I'd be very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: How can the problem with the program persist if it is removed? Perhaps you should clarify the issue a bit more.

Comment: After I do the purge thing there are still a couple of .xml files that I cannot delete.

Comment: Unlike Windows, when you uninstall a program, it doesn't clear your configuration. To clear your configuration, delete the file `~/.config/kritarc`

Comment: Still it is not clear to me what still "freezes" after you removed the program. You indicate that the problem persists even after purging the program. Please clarify in your question: use "edit" to update it.

Comment: I meant that I purged the program and then I reinstalled it once again but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem might not be with Krita, but some other setting or software.

I recommend installing and running the program `atop`. It allows you to check which bottleneck your computer is hitting: CPU, general disk IO, disk IO due to swapping, network etc. Here are the steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new Terminal window
2. Run `sudo apt install atop`
3. Run `sudo atop`
4. Wait until the "activity since boot" disappears.
5. Look for red text - this is your culprit.

Comment: I tried but there's no red text.